# Exam questions where both options looked acceptable

Tags: conditional-constructions, exam-questions

> 1. (If/Suppose) I hadn't done well in the exam I wouldn't have passed the course.
> 2. If she was fed, she (would have been / would be) calm.
> 3. There (is said / was said) to be a better turnout at the staff meetings than last year.

I felt like these three questions could have been answered in either way.

Comment: You are misspelling the word "I", which should always be spelled with a capital letter.

Comment: The third one could be answered either way, because it's a poorly-worded sentence.  But the first two have one clear answer.

Comment: @Andrew what are the answers for the first two ?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the grammar is identical from your test – a question, since you don't consistently capitalize – then here are the correct answers and why:

1. "If" is the correct answer.  "Suppose" could only have worked if it was structured as two sentences.

> Suppose I hadn't done well in the exam.  I wouldn't have passed the
>   course.

2. "would have been" is the correct answer.  The sentence begins in past tense, and "would be" is future tense.  "would have been" keeps everything past tense.
3. "was said" is the correct answer.  Contextually, it makes the most sense.  "was said" references a previous conversation.  "is said" implies a cultural belief by a large group of people.

Comment: Actually I think your answers and your reasons for both #2 and #3 are incorrect and based on insufficient logic.  For #2, "would have been" is appropriate if the first part of the sentence was "If she **had been** fed".  Since it's not, then "would be" is fine, as it's the *hypothetical*, not the *future tense*.   For #3  I think either *was* or *is* works, because it's an ugly sentence in which the time frame is not clear.   You are right that "is said" implies a *common belief*, but this has nothing to do with culture.  It could just be people I know.